# Meteor Facebook Login Error Accounts.LoginCancelledError: No matching login attempt found

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, oauth

I get the following strange Error in my meteor application when users try to login with facebook. Its not that all logins are not working but as we launched today i get 4 or 5 every hour. Which also means im loosing many users.

Error:

```
Accounts.LoginCancelledError: No matching login attempt found
```

Method which throws the error(its called on client side):

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['email']}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
            }
            else
            {
                Router.go('browseCampaigns');
            }
        });
```

Also i add the FB Profile Picture in the onCreateUser() Method:

```
  user.services[service].picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" +  user.services[service].id + "/picture/?type=large";
```

Can this cause this problem?

Comment: Did you get around this issue?

Comment: Sadly not, still getting tickets from time to time....

Comment: My app was working fine for the last few weeks and now I'm getting this error. It has totally crashed my site traffic. I'm stuck as I'm not sure how to debug or where to start! Help -- "No matching login attempt found"

Answer (score 1):

If you have facebook working when you test it this can be caused by:

- the user closing the popup before authorising your app
- your app being unable to talk to facebook (unlikely if you have logins working/if the site is hosted on commercial servers)

There's not much that can be done in the first case. You've mentioned in your code you ask the user for their email address. If a user is uncomfortable with this they are likely to close the login popup.

Comment: no sadly thats not the reason, i talked to a user. She just wanted to login and accepted the details in the facebook window.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by an access to the application via `http` instead of `https`.

Compare two versions:

- `http://admin-react.herokuapp.com/`
- `https://admin-react.herokuapp.com/`

the first will not work.